# Get UISegmentedController value from flipside

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

If you just have a utility template provided by SDK with a segmented controller on the flipsideview with several segments of a decimal value, and you want to grab the current value for the mainview, what is the best way to do this? Thank you for taking the time to answer!

MainViewController.m

```
-(void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    //This does get the value, but only by going to the flipside first then back to the mainview.
    SegValueLabel.text = [controller.RiseSegmentedControl titleForSegmentAtIndex:controller.RiseSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex];
}

-(IBAction)CalculateButton:(id)sender{
    //Need to get the value of segmented control from FlipSideView and assign it a variable.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the segmented controller is mapped to an IBOutlet property in the flipside view.  If you are using the Apple utility app template, you'll see that FlipsideViewControllerDelegate is implemented by MainViewController.  If you aren't using it, make a project using it as an example.  Implement the `flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:` method in MainView and use it to grab the property something like this:

```
flipsideController.segmentedControlProperty.selectedIndex;
```

or if you want the title:

```
[flipsideController.segmentedControlProperty titleForSegmentAtIndex:flipsideController.segmentedControlProperty.selectedIndex];
```

Comment: Apologies, but "segmentedControlProperty" isn't even an option after FlipSideViewcontroller. I do have my segmented controls to an IBOutlet. I also tried under the flipsideviewdidfinish FlipSideViewController.UISegmentedControl but there are no completions after that, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That was an example.  Replace segmentedControlProperty with whatever you named your IBOutlet.  I'll need to see your code to make a comment on if something is wrong there.

Comment: There is another similar question I have posted with the code, it's for the same project. It doesn't show my object for some reason...

Comment: It shows up if I use `- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller {
    
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    controller.RiseSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;


}` but how can I take that to my calculate method? It doesn't see anything from `flipsideViewControllerDidFinish`

Comment: @Peter DeWeese, what your showing for the answer doesn't seem to work...could you be more specific? Once it's added to the Flipsideviewcontrollerdidfinish, how do you access it from another method?

Comment: Also, I was able to get the value from the flipsideview segmentedControl on a test app, but the value only shows up if you go to the flipside, then back to the main, which is not what I want, I want it to be able to read it from app startup because I have set some default values for the segmentedControl, which is saved using NSUserDefaults. What I am trying to do, is retrieve the values of the segmentedControls from within my calculate method. Is there anyway to do this?