# Pass Data Between Two UIViewControllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I need to pass data of UILabel from ViewB to ViewA. My ViewA has a UILabel with some number. This number can be changed in ViewB which I open as a new UIViewController as below:

```
viewB = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
```

ViewB also has a UILabel to hold the same value. I tried to pass this value from ViewB to ViewA by assigning UILabel's like so:

```
viewB.countdownLabel = self.countdownLabel;
```

That didn't work. Thanks for suggestions...

Comment: have you added your label programmatically or using IB in your next view (ViewB) ?

Comment: Check out this link: [Passing values between views][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466195/get-uisegmentedcontroller-value-from-flipside/5466326#5466326

Comment: Check out this link: [Passing values between views][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466195/get-uisegmentedcontroller-value-from-flipside/5466326#5466326

Comment: Check out this link: [Passing values between views][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466195/get-uisegmentedcontroller-value-from-flipside/5466326#5466326

Answer (score 3):

i think what you want is:
`viewB.countdownLabel.text = self.countdownLabel.text`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure viewB.countdownLabel is a retain property and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

By saying "viewB.countdownLabel = self.countdownLabel;" you are simply making viewB's countdownLabel a reference to the original label, you're not copying their values. You need to do the following...

```
[viewB.countdownLabel setText:self.countdownLabel];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use `AppDelegate` to pass the value across to any `viewController` (and read the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW25)).

```
GeneralAppDelegate*appDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplicaton] delegate];
myLocalProperty=appDelegate.someDataModelProperty;
```

or just use

```
viewB.countdownLabel.text = self.countdownLabel.text;
```

in your code.

Comment: Every time you use AppDelegate for something like that, god kills a kitten.

Comment: Alternatively look at NSNotifcationCenter as a means of message passing without the need to couple classes/controllers.

Answer (score 0):

KVO also can be used.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177-BCICJDHA